# Not able to add taskbar icon to node webkit application

Tags: reactjs, node-webkit

I have created React application and bundled it using `nw-react-scripts`. I am trying to add icon for taskbar, but icon doesn't change. Always I see default icon. I tried by clearing appData as well. I have used below method in my `package.json` to add icon. Help me out in resolving this issue.

```
"window": {
 "icon":"src/image/logo.png"
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If am getting it right, this would work.

In your HTML template (usually `index.html` or `template.html`, try this:
`<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/your/favicon.ext">`

replace the href with your icon path. it's favorable to name it `favicon.png` instead of `logo.png`.

If am wrong, can you please tell what TASK BAR ICON MEANS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have <link /> tag added in my html and my fav icon works fine. am using window 7 64bit system. when any application is launched on windows, we see a application icon on taskbar below with logo of it. Am not able to get that icon changed, it's showing default icon. i have updated my question with image please refer.